# Save flutter files in location accessable from the android files app

Tags: android, flutter, filesystems

I want to save audio files in my flutter app, but in addition to them being available inside the app, I also want to access them from the android [files](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files) app. Is there a location that can be accessed from both?

I have tried saving the files to the downloads directory, but I am only able to find folders, not the files in that folder using the flutter IO package:

```
io.Directory("/storage/emulated/0/Download/").listSync()
```

Is there another location I can use, or another code snippet I can use to get files from both flutter and the files app?

Comment: do you have the permission to read external storage in your manifest?

Comment: No, I did not. If you write this as the answer, I will accept:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add permission in Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”/>
```